# Issues Splitting CSV files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv, split

Im trying to split a csv file into multiple files using the below command..This command splits into 5 files but the data is truncated in one of the file?

How do I fix this issue?

```
>>split -n 5 -d -a 2  testfile
```

I have 5001 lines in my input but the split splits into

```
file1 - 932
file2 - 910
file3 - 1149
file4 - 1044
file5 - 966
```

Shouldn't it be 1000 lines per file?

Comment: I hope you realize that the output of a split (with `-n` but **also** with `-l`) operation on a CSV file is not necessarily a valid CSV file. Of course it might not matter to you, or not apply to your particular input.

Comment: I don't understand why spliting using '-l' (number of lines) might not be valid CSV? Because the header row is only present in the first file? Or something else?

Answer (score 8):

`split -n 5` splits the file into five parts making all but the last part have the same number of *bytes*.

If you want to do splitting only on line boundaries, use:

```
split -n l/5 -d -a 2  testfile
```

This is detailed in the [GNU docs for `split`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html) as follows:

> ‘-n chunks’ 
>   ‘--number=chunks’ 
>             Split input to chunks output files where chunks may be:
>
> ```
>           n      generate n files based on current size of input
>           k/n    only output kth of n to stdout
>           l/n    generate n files without splitting lines
>           l/k/n  likewise but only output kth of n to stdout
>           r/n    like ‘l’ but use round robin distribution
>           r/k/n  likewise but only output kth of n to stdout
> ```

Another option is to specify how many lines you want in each output file:

```
split -l 1000 -d -a 2  testfile
```

The above splits the file into parts, each (except the last)  with 1,000 lines.  This is documented as:

> ‘-l lines’
>  ‘--lines=lines’
>            Put lines lines of input into each output file.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-l` option of `split`. From the man page:

```
 -l line_count
         Create smaller files n lines in length.
```

e.g.

```
split -l 1000 afile.txt
```

Comment: What is the problem with -n option?

Comment: From the man page `-n` is for chunks so, it will ignore newlines I suppose.